# What does the clock item do?

Tags: klonoa

There are several clock items in each level, but I don't see picking them up do anything notable. It's as if it has no effect in the game. What does it actually do?
[image: Screenshot of the Wii remake of the original Klonoa: Door to Phantomile PS1 game with Klonoa about to pick up a clock item]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the Alarm Clock. It servers as a checkpoint item. When your health reaches zero, you will respawn at the last picked up Alarm Clock.

> The whole adventure is taking place in a dream, so it kind of makes sense to "wake up" in case of failure at the appropriate point.